# how awk takes the result of a unix command as a parameter?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Say there is an input file with tabs delimited field, the first field is integer

```
1 abc
1 def
1 ghi
1 lalala
1 heyhey
2 ahb
2 bbh
3 chch
3 chchch
3 oiohho
3 nonon
3 halal
3 whatever
```

First, i need to compute the counts of the unique values in the first field, that will be:

```
5 for 1, 2 for 2, and 6 for 3
```

Then I need to find the max of these counts, in this case, it's 6.

Now i need to pass "6" to another awk script as a parmeter.

I know i can use command below to get a list of count:

```
cut -f1 input.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | sort
```

but how do i get the first count number and pass it to the next awk command as a parameter not as an input file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This AWK script replaces your whole pipeline:

```
awk -v parameter="$(awk '{a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) {if (a[i] > max) {max = a[i]}}; print max}' inputfile)" '{print parameter}' otherfile
```

where `'{print parameter}'` is a standin for your other AWK script and "otherfile" is the input for that script.

**Note:** It is ***extremely*** likely that the two AWK scripts could be combined into one which would be less of a hack than doing it in a way such as that outlined in your question (`awk` feeding `awk`).

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me again! :) I like the way you compute max. Agreed on your note, is there a way for me to write a function within one awk script that also calls awk? Have a great sunday! :)

Comment: @nanshi: You shouldn't need to all awk within awk since you're already in awk. There are techniques that are used to deal with multiple files, handling each in its own way. If you post a question that asks how to process the two parts in one script and show how those parts interact, I or someone else will try to answer.

Comment: god save me~~~Dennis, both you and sarnold's answers are good, but i can only mark one..~~~>.<~~~

Comment: Dennis, new question is here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874780/awk-how-two-scripts-interact-with-each-other

Comment: @nanshi: Dennis's answer is clearly better -- don't feel the least bit bad about accepting his answer instead of mine. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is nothing very specific for awk.

Either a program can read from stdin, then you can pass the input with a pipe:

```
prg1 | prg2
```

or your program expects input as parameter, then you use

```
prg2 $(prg1)
```

Note that in both cases prg1 is processed before prg2.

Some programs allow both possibilities, while a huge amount of data is rarely passed as argument.

Comment: +1, but in the pipe case, prg1 is *not* processed before prg2.  They run concurrently.  Certainly it is likely that prg2 will block on a read and start running after prg1 outputs some data, so you can almost always say that prg2 is processing data after prg1 sees it (but prg2 might be ignoring the output from prg1), but the whole point of the pipe is that you get concurrency for free.

Comment: Well, yes, that wasn't correct, but prg2 will - if it is build to read input - block until the input arrives, and if prg1 finishes after producing the last output, it will produce all output, hand it to prg2, which might be fast enough to still finish before prg1 in a race condition, but from a producer-consumer viewpoint, prg1 will be the producer and prg2 the consumer. It might often be more interesting that you needn't keep all the data in memory while executing both programs, than the speed of parallel invocation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shell's `$()` command substitution:

```
awk -f script -v num=$(cut -f1 input.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | sort | tail -1) < input_file
```

(I added the `tail -1` to ensure that at most one line is used.)

Comment: so that the last input_file is another awk script? how does another script takes the value out as a parameter? Say $(...) is being evaluated as 6, but in the next awk (that is in a script file), how does it take 6 as a parameter?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I figured out my last question :) do a awk param=$() :)

Comment: The _another `awk` script_ in my example is stored in `script`. If you want to just put it all on the command line, you could. Since it appears you didn't already know how to access the variable from `awk`, I decided to look a little further and found that it is easier to use `-v name=value` to assign the variable `name` a specific value at execution time. So I edited my answer to include the `-v num`, just access the `num` variable from within the script.

Comment: sarnold, I have a hard time to mark whose answer is correct...since both are nice solutions. Thank all you guys for helping me! :)

Comment: can i run awk within an awk function? can i run $(...) within an awk function? I guess this is my real question. If i can do this, then my awk script can be basically documented well and more powerful